# Open the excel new file after complete operation

Tags: vba, excel

hi what i am doing right now is scrapping data. after the process complete it will pop msgbox "Completed" and the new file contains the data will be save to network path. my question is. what code do i need to add so that. after the scraping operation complete, it will automatically open the new file created by the scrap tool.

Here is my code

```
Global FilePath As String
Global strPath As String


Declare Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" _
      Alias "WNetGetUserA" (ByVal lpName As String, _
      ByVal lpUserName As String, lpnLength As Long) As Long

   Const NoError = 0

Sub Clear_Internet_Cache()
    Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"
End Sub
''==========================================================================================
''Copy_Paste function creates the log of excel files with the issues in it
''==========================================================================================
Function Copy_Paste() As String

Dim SourceBook As Workbook
Dim DBook As Workbook
Dim strPath As String
Dim count As Double
Dim name As String
Dim TemplateBook, MyTime, Mydate As String
Dim FileName As String

Dim directoryName As String
Dim FY1 As String
Dim WK As String
Dim MyInput As Integer
Dim layer As String
Dim CrawlerName As String
Dim fixedpath As String
Dim region As String
Dim segment As String

If Sheet1.Cells(2, 6) = "Upload to Sharedrive" Then

fixedpath = "\\"

FY1 = Sheet1.Cells(2, 7)
WK = Sheet1.Cells(2, 8)

MyInput = Sheet9.Cells(3, 26)

CrawlerName = "AIO"
region = "EMEA"
segment = Sheet1.Cells(2, 9)

If MyInput = 1 Then

layer = "Staging"

Else

layer = "Production"

End If

   ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''FOR USER NAME

      Const lpnLength As Integer = 255
      Dim status As Integer
      Dim lpName, lpUserName As String
      lpUserName = Space$(lpnLength + 1)
      status = WNetGetUser(lpName, lpUserName, lpnLength)

      If status = NoError Then

             lpUserName = Left$(lpUserName, InStr(lpUserName, Chr(0)) - 1)

      End If


      '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

   directoryName = fixedpath & "\" & region
    If Not DirExists(directoryName) Then
        MkDir (directoryName)
    End If

     directoryName = fixedpath & "\" & region & "\" & segment
    If Not DirExists(directoryName) Then
        MkDir (directoryName)
    End If


     directoryName = fixedpath & "\" & region & "\" & segment & "\" & FY1
    If Not DirExists(directoryName) Then
        MkDir (directoryName)
    End If


     directoryName = fixedpath & "\" & region & "\" & segment & "\" & FY1 & "\" & WK

    If Not DirExists(directoryName) Then
        MkDir (directoryName)
    End If

     directoryName = fixedpath & "\" & region & "\" & segment & "\" & FY1 & "\" & WK & "\" & layer

    If Not DirExists(directoryName) Then
        MkDir (directoryName)
    End If


    directoryName = fixedpath & "\" & region & "\" & segment & "\" & FY1 & "\" & WK & "\" & layer & "\" & CrawlerName

    If Not DirExists(directoryName) Then
        MkDir (directoryName)
    End If

    strPath = directoryName


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

TemplateBook = "AIO_Report"
TemplateBook = Left(TemplateBook, Len(TemplateBook) - 5)
Mydate = Format(Date, "mmm d yyyy")
MyTime = Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss")
MyTime = Replace(MyTime, ":", "_")
FileName = TemplateBook & "_" & Mydate & "_" & MyTime
FilePath = ""
FilePath = strPath & "\" & FileName & "_" & lpUserName & ".xlsx"



Set SourceBook = ActiveWorkbook

Set DBook = Workbooks.Add

SourceBook.Sheets("Bundle List").Cells.copy Destination:=DBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells

DBook.Sheets("Sheet1").name = "Error Report"

Sheets("Error Report").Select


With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With


    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete

    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete


    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

DBook.SaveCopyAs FilePath

DBook.Close False






End If

Sheets("Bundle List").Select
Columns("W:An").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Columns("a").Select

MsgBox ("Completed.")

Application.StatusBar = ""


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you saved some file such as "xyz.xlsx", 
call something like

```
Shell("cmd /c ..pathto...xyz.xlsx")
```

what it will do is to launch cmd prompt as a conduit to launching the program 
registered for xlsx. It will work for any registered extension such as pdf.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: You need to use that line of code in your VBA to open the file you saved

Comment: the filename is auto generate by the code. how do i define in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If DBook is the file you want left open, then I'd probably change this:

```
DBook.SaveCopyAs FilePath
DBook.Close False
```

To:

```
DBook.SaveAs FilePath
```

This will leave the workbook open, and you've already saved it. Just keep it open for the user to have their way with. As for `SaveCopyAs` don't think you need to save a copy of an unsaved workbook, right? Have fun!

Comment: I changed that. run time error came out 438: object doesnt support this property or method. then the file is just open but no file saved to sharedrive